# Using a For loop with BigIntegers creates memory problems with Java. [Android]

Tags: java, android, for-loop, memory, biginteger

Im currently trying to loop through a BigInteger like so...

```
BigInteger y;
BigInteger yu = BigInteger.valueOf(17);
for(y= new BigInteger("96");y.compareTo(yu.add(y)) < 0;y=y.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"y="+y,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
```

For the purposes of this example I only used 96 but the same thing occurs for higher numbers. When I begin the program the screen goes black and log.cat displays the following messages:

```
10-26 19:15:49.853 5043-5043/everything.ofjd.com.everythingform D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9202K, 48% free 16294K/30792K, paused 162ms, total 162ms

10-26 19:15:50.923 5043-5043/everything.ofjd.com.everythingform D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9530K, 52% free 14955K/30792K, paused 155ms, total 156ms

10-26 19:15:51.983 5043-5043/everything.ofjd.com.everythingform D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9037K, 55% free 14110K/30792K, paused 146ms, total 147ms

10-26 19:15:53.018 5043-5043/everything.ofjd.com.everythingform D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8207K, 55% free 14094K/30792K, paused 141ms, total 141ms

10-26 19:15:54.068 5043-5043/everything.ofjd.com.everythingform D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8172K, 55% free 14114K/30792K, paused 143ms, total 143ms
```

Log.cat continues to log 55% as long as the app is running, does anyone know why this is?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: What do you think your for loop is doing?

Comment: @Kayaman What do you mean?

Comment: In your opinion, what does the for loop do?

Comment: It loops through a specific section of code as long as the terms are satisfied @Kayaman

Comment: Yes, that's (sort of) the definition for a `for` loop, but I was asking about **your** `for` loop.

Comment: It should display the toast message 17 times. @Kayaman

Comment: So instead of doing `for(int i = 0;i < 17;i++)` why did you get all the terms wrong and use `BigInteger` for absolutely no reason?

Comment: `y.compareTo(yu.add(y)) < 0` says "y is smaller than y + 17", which is always true, so you've created an infinite loop. What are you trying to do?

Comment: ahh thank you very much, apologies, I understand now. @PaulBoddington

Comment: No problem. However, I agree with Kayaman that you should just use `int`. You only need to use `BigInteger` if the loop variable can be bigger than `9223372036854775807`

Comment: To be clear: `9223372036854775807` is the limit for a `long`. For an `int` loop variable, the max is `2147483647`.

Answer (score 2):

```
10-26 19:15:49.853 5043-5043/everything.ofjd.com.everythingform D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9202K, 48% free 16294K/30792K, paused 162ms, total 162ms
10-26 19:15:50.923 5043-5043/everything.ofjd.com.everythingform D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9530K, 52% free 14955K/30792K, paused 155ms, total 156ms
10-26 19:15:51.983 5043-5043/everything.ofjd.com.everythingform D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9037K, 55% free 14110K/30792K, paused 146ms, total 147ms
10-26 19:15:53.018 5043-5043/everything.ofjd.com.everythingform D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8207K, 55% free 14094K/30792K, paused 141ms, total 141ms
10-26 19:15:54.068 5043-5043/everything.ofjd.com.everythingform D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8172K, 55% free 14114K/30792K, paused 143ms, total 143ms
```

Let's take that piece by piece:

- `GC_FOR_ALLOC` means we had to garbage-collect because there was no room for an allocation you tried to make.
- `freed 9202K` means that the GC managed to free about 9 MB of RAM, so that's good.
- `48% free 16294K/30792K` means that now, about half of your heap is in use. There is about 14 MB free heap space.
- `paused 162ms` means that your thread had to wait for 0.162 seconds for this garbage collection to be run.

Now, why are you seeing all of these?

Because you're allocating and throwing aways lots of objects. Those ~9 MB that the garbage collector keeps freeing? They come from objects that are no longer referenced.

I would recommend that you use the "Allocation Tracker" tool in Android DDMS. It'll show you all your allocations, and where each one was made. It should help you track down the source of all these garbage objects being created.

But yeah, like the comments on the question have already stated: your loop was going forever, and creating lots of BigInteger objects -- since each `add()` call will allocate a new BigInteger. Since it goes forever, those numbers will become pretty big, increasing the size of each individual BigInteger object as well.

But seriously, try the "Allocation Tracker" tool. It's good to know, and you'll gain a better understanding of what went wrong here.